# Ansible register variable in task and use it in template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

In the Ansible task, how to register a variable so I can use it as check statement in Template. The tasks are:

```
- name: Check if certificate file exists
  stat: path=/etc/nginx/ssl/{{ sitename }}.pem
  register: ssl_cert_check

- name: Create vhost from template
  template: "src={{ vhost_conf }} dest=/etc/nginx/conf/vhost.conf"
```

In the template of vhost for `listen 80` is always available and I want to add the block for `listen 443` only when the certificate is available:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  ........

}
{% if ssl_cert_check == True %} # This doesn't issue error but doesn't work either
server {
  listen 443;
  ..............
}
{% endif %}
```

When I run the above case the second server block is not executed, it means only the server listen 80 is printed in the vhost config.

However if I remove the True for `if` statement and add `stat.exists` in the template then I get error:

```
# This issues error
{% if ssl_cert_check.stat.exists %}
server {
  listen 443;
  ..............
}
{% endif %}
```

The error is:
`"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'` even though I used stat module before registering the variable.

Is there any other way to pass the variable defined in Ansible task and use it in Jinja2 template?

The value displayed by a `- debug: var=ssl_cert_check` task before the `Create vhost from template` is:

```
"ssl_cert_check": {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "changed": false, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "checksum_algorithm": "sha1", 
                        "follow": false, 
                        "get_checksum": true, 
                        "get_md5": true, 
                        "mime": false, 
                        "path": "/etc/nginx/ssl/abc.pem"
                    }, 
                    "module_name": "stat"
                }, 
                "item": {
                    ........
                }, 
                "stat": {
                    "exists": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the debug message, please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `ssl_cert_check` you have, you will notice the Boolean key `exists` is stored in the `stat` dictionary under `results` list, so in fact you should iterate over the items on the list inside the template.

If what you posted is a consistent example, you can refer to the first item on the list using:

```
{% if ssl_cert_check.results[0].stat.exists %}
```

---

However the way `ssl_cert_check` is created in your case most likely means:

- you have some kind of loop in your code
- `sitename` is not a scalar value, but a list itself

If the loop ran more times, or you had more than one item on `sitename`, your results might not be consistent.

You should rather fix the root cause than go with `results[0]` workaround.

Comment: thanks for the tips, I learned from you a lot about debugging... But to answer my question precisely there is `array` of results, so, `{% if ssl_cert_check.results[0].stat.exists %}` did work... it didn't work with just `results` so I had to add that `[0]` as its first array. If you edit that in your answer then I will accept it. Thank you once again.

Comment: There is an array because of what you decided to not to include in your question. If it were only what you published, it would work with `ssl_cert_check.stat.exists`.

Comment: I'm not sure how the array comes there, but if I used the same registered variable in the task like `-name: abc #\n file: #its task \n when: ssl_cert_check.stat.exists` then `ssl_cert_check.stat.exists` works perfectly. Only using that variable in Jinja template was the issue and adding `results[0]` did fix that one as well.

Comment: The problem is most likely because your `sitename` is not a scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware: skipped tasks will still register variable:

```
- name: Check if certificate file exists
  stat: path=/etc/nginx/ssl/{{ sitename }}.pem
  register: ssl_cert_check

- name: Check if certificate file exists
  stat: path=/etc/nginx/ssl/{{ sitename }}.pem
  register: ssl_cert_check
  when: nonexistent is defined
```

In this case, register will have the value:

```
"ssl_cert_check": {
    "changed": false,
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False",
    "skipped": true
}
```

Most probably best to use unique names for each register?